# ASP.NET: How can you add a custom/namespaced XHTML attribute to a web control declaratively?

Tags: asp.net, xhtml, web-controls, custom-attributes

Normally, unknown attributes of a webcontrol are passed through to to the rendered element in the browser.  So the following works.

```
<asp:label runat="server" Text="Label Text" helpId="101" />
```

However, if you use a namespaced attribute like the following

```
<asp:label runat="server" Text="Label Text" myNs:helpId="101" /></div>
```

The attribute is not rendered to the client, even when the custom namespace is declared in the html element like:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:myNs="http://www.acme.com/htmlext">
```

Does anyone know of a way to get this to render to the client, without having to use a custom control.   A module or other globally "pluggable" solution would be acceptable.

Comment: After viewing the generated page source, it was apparent that using an attribute prefix as I am attempting is interpreted by the asp.net compiler as a device filter, which causes the attribute to only be written for the specified device alias.  I am not sure how to work around this since there is no way to become familiar with the page compiler internals.

Answer (score 0):

Found [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.addattributestorender.aspx) on MSDN... looks promising.
But you will need to create a custom webcontrol.

### WebControl.AddAttributesToRender Method

Adds HTML attributes and styles that need to be rendered to the specified HtmlTextWriterTag.

```
[System.Security.Permissions.PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Name="FullTrust")] 
  protected override void AddAttributesToRender(HtmlTextWriter writer) 
  {

     writer.AddAttribute("myNs:helpId", "101");
     base.AddAttributesToRender(writer);

  }
```

Comment: Thanks, I saw this as well but I was hoping to locate something generic that would allow it to work with all existing controls.